# struct.push(); error ( Member "push" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in struct)

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract SimpleToken is ERC20{
    constructor(uint256 initialSupply) ERC20("SimpleToken", "ALPH") {
        _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply);
    }

    FFA[] public FFAArray;


    struct FFA
    {
        string Name;
        address Creator;
        address Wallet;
        uint8 entryFee;
        uint256 maxentries;
        uint8 validatorReward;
    }


    function CreateFFA(string memory _Name,uint256 _maxentries,uint256 _entryFee,uint8 _validatorReward) public
    {
        FFAArray.push(_Name,msg.sender,msg.sender,_entryFee,_maxentries,_validatorReward);
    }
}
```

Error:Member "push" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in struct  at `FFAArray.push(_Name,msg.sender,msg.sender,_entryFee,_maxentries,_validatorReward);`
Can someone tell me why i am getting this error its like solidity thinks FFAArray is not array but struct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must passed the struct defined into FFAarray variable.
In your line of code:

```
FFAArray.push(_Name,msg.sender,msg.sender,_entryFee,_maxentries,_validatorReward);
```

you aren't defining a new instance of struct but you're passing the parameters to the array while these last have to passed to a new instance of struct.
Having said that, you can use this way to insert a new FFA's struct.

```
function CreateFFA(string memory _Name, uint256 _maxentries, uint8 _entryFee, uint8 _validatorReward) public
{
    FFAArray.push(FFA(_Name, msg.sender, msg.sender, _entryFee, _maxentries, _validatorReward));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not pushing a FFA type data, additionally the datatype of _entryFee is wrong.

```
    function CreateFFA(string memory _Name,uint256 _maxentries,uint8 _entryFee,uint8 _validatorReward) public
    {
        FFA memory newFFa = FFA(_Name, msg.sender, msg.sender, _entryFee, _maxentries, _validatorReward);
        FFAArray.push(newFFa);
    }
```

Comment: you saying i need to create new instance every time i trying to push on array ? i was thinking array have its own constructor and can do that on its own if right parameters are passed

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use the no parameter push() to get a reference to the new `FFA`.

```
function CreateFFA(
    string memory _Name, 
    uint256 _maxentries, 
    uint256 _entryFee, 
    uint8 _validatorReward
) public {
    // Get storage reference
    FFA storage ffa = FFAArray.push();

    // Update fields
    ffa.Name = _Name;
    ffa.Creator = msg.sender;
    ffa.Wallet = msg.sender;
    ffa.entryFee = uint8(_entryFee);
    ffa.maxentries = _maxentries;
    ffa.validatorReward = _validatorReward;
}
```